# Run sql scripts using batch file

Tags: sql, batch-file, psql

I am trying to create a batch file that connects to my local Postgres 14 server and creates tables by opening a .sql file that contains all the table scripts.

For now, I was able to connect to the server using this code:

`psql -U postgres -h localhost -d test`

This command opens the command prompt and asks for the password. After this, how do I update the batch file to insert the password and automtically install the tables from my .sql file?

Comment: Have you tried using the search facility at the top of the page? Perhaps [\[batch-file\]\[psql\]password](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D%5Bpsql%5Dpassword) would be a good start. Please do not ask questions before having checked to see if they have been asked and answered before.

Comment: add `-a -f myInsertFile` behind the command